# How to find all occurrences of groups of single letters in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Now a days most people that post on forums or any other place on the web seem to love to add a space to every letter to a random word. I know that there is even a name for it but I am too tire that I can't remember. Usually you will see this  on post titles.

So I have a project where I will use a regular expression to find all these group of single letters to try to concatenate them and hopefully put them back into a word.

Now I have most of my project already done but I always get stuck with regular expressions because I just don't get it. I am okay with most of the basics of programming and the logic but regular expressions I still don't get them.

So if anyone can help me with the following regex pattern I will really appreciated.

I want to do the following when someone submits some text. To look for any group of 3 or more single letters that are separated by a space and are between words

```
$string = "Lorem i p s u m dolor sit a m e t, consectetur adipiscing e l i.";

// I know thats as far as I got with the pattern
$pattern = "/\s([a-zA-Z{1}])\s\w+/";

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

So the code above should output:

```
Array 
(
   [0] => i p s u m
   [1] => a m e t
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is `e l i` not selected?

Comment: It was really late when I was trying to ask the question I had spend all night trying to find a regex pattern that I forgot about the the last group e l i

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following regular expression:

```
\b\p{L}(?:\h+\p{L}){2,}\b(?![\s\p{P}]*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bL0fL9/2)

It will match at least 3 letters separated with space only if not at the end of a "sentence" (not matched if followed with any whitespace with punctuation at the end of the string).

IDEONE [code demo](http://ideone.com/EtwoaB):

```
$re = '~\b\p{L}(?:\h+\p{L}){2,}\b(?![\s\p{P}]*$)~u'; 
$str = "Lorem i p s u m dolor sit a m e t, consectetur adipiscing e l i.";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

The regex matches:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `\p{L}` - one letter
- `(?:\h+\p{L}){2,}` - 2 or more sequences of one or more horizontal whitespace (`\h+`) followed with a letter
- `\b` - trailing word boundary
- `(?![\s\p{P}]*$)` - match only if not followed with zero or more whitespace or punctuation before the end of string.

Comment: If it works for you, I will add the regex explanation.

Comment: I've added the regex explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use look ahead along with repetitions,

```
/(?:\s[a-zA-Z](?=[\s,.])){3,}/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/gR9pQ5/1)

Comment: Thank you the patter works also as the above thank you ill put both on my project see which one will give me the best results. As you know people tend to submit weird combination of letters to make their post stand out. But I do appreciate the big help you guys have given me .